# joomla blueflame forms can't delete and can't install

Tags: joomla2.5, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to install or uninstall bfforms for joomla 2.5.19.

I'm getting a 403 error.  I've checked the permissions and the folder has 755 and the file 644.  I must be going mad because it keeps throwing he 403 error and I can't think why.

Bf forms gives the following output:

```
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
 ../plugins/system/blueflame/bfCombine.php?type=js&c=form&f=mootools...[FAILED]
```

if I look into the debug it says 403 error.

Anyone have any idea what I can do.  At the very least I'd like to manually remove the bfforms component.

thanks - if you can help you'll stop me from pulling all my hair out :)